# What is wrong with nextjs new api routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, app-router

I am currently getting this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
And my code is:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { IDPay } from 'idpay';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const apiKey = '';
const idpayAPI = new IDPay(apiKey);

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    console.log(req);
  const { id,order_id } = await req.json()
   
  const response = await idpayAPI.verifyPayment({
    id: id,
    order_id: order_id
  });

  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(response.status));
}
```

I want to get 2 parameters from the data that is posted, one is ID and the other is ORDER ID. Don't know why I get this error. I am using typescript too.

I've tried using req.body but that still didn't worked. I tried searching and even on the actual nextjs document, they say the correct way is this, while for me its not working.

Output from `console.log(req)`

```
NextRequest [Request] {
  [Symbol(realm)]: {
    settingsObject: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] }
  },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    method: 'POST',
    localURLsOnly: false,
    unsafeRequest: false,
    body: { stream: undefined, source: null, length: null },
    client: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] },
    reservedClient: null,
    replacesClientId: '',
    window: 'client',
    keepalive: false,
    serviceWorkers: 'all',
    initiator: '',
    destination: '',
    priority: null,
    origin: 'client',
    policyContainer: 'client',
    referrer: 'client',
    referrerPolicy: '',
    mode: 'cors',
    useCORSPreflightFlag: true,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    useCredentials: false,
    cache: 'default',
    redirect: 'follow',
    integrity: '',
    cryptoGraphicsNonceMetadata: '',
    parserMetadata: '',
    reloadNavigation: false,
    historyNavigation: false,
    userActivation: false,
    taintedOrigin: false,
    redirectCount: 0,
    responseTainting: 'basic',
    preventNoCacheCacheControlHeaderModification: false,
    done: false,
    timingAllowFailed: false,
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [Array]
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    url: URL {
      href: 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback',
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      pathname: '/api/callback',
      search: '',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
      hash: ''
    }
  },
  [Symbol(signal)]: AbortSignal { aborted: false },
  [Symbol(abortController)]: AbortController { signal: AbortSignal { aborted: false } },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(19) {
      'accept' => [Object],
      'accept-encoding' => [Object],
      'accept-language' => [Object],
      'cache-control' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'host' => [Object],
      'origin' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-platform' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-dest' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-mode' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-site' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-user' => [Object],
      'sec-gpc' => [Object],
      'upgrade-insecure-requests' => [Object],
      'user-agent' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array]
    ]
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookies: RequestCookies { _parsed: Map(0) {}, _headers: [HeadersList] },
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    nextUrl: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] },
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where this function is getting called. What is `req`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @phuzi, req is for NextJS Request. You can read their documents here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application

Comment: I've added the pastebin stuff to the question. Looking at it though shows that the body of the request is empty/null. "Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0" would suggest though that the content actuall starts with an `s`

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0`: this means that parsing the request body to JSON with `await req.json()` failed, because as it says, the request body is invalid JSON syntax. This is a problem with the request, not with the code. What does the console.log print?

Comment: Thanks for the response! It prints: https://pastebin.com/cbFQsDdv

Comment: @ArashAmini I added the output to your question so that others can see the ouptut without digging through the answers and the comments to them. Always add relevant details like this to the question. Preferably inline too.